# how to implement flextable with empty cell

Tags: gwt

I would like to use FlexTable to implement the below format:

```
Empty a  Empty b  c
Empty d  Empty e  f
Empty g  Empty h  i
```

a~i are widgets and Empty stands for empty cell. I would like to know how I can have empty cells which has the same widths and height of those widgets(all widgets are the same size) in the Flextable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but there is no such thing like empty cell in FlexTable (*afaik*) .As an alternative, add an empty string.

```
 ft.setText(x,y, "");
 ft.getCellFormatter().addStyleName(x, y, "styleNameWithHeightWidth");
```

Answer (score -4):

There is a way without using CSS:

```
flexTable.setHTML(x, y, "");
```